# How to show more than 5 posts?

Tags: query, get-posts, categories

I am running code that shows child categories, and all posts in the child categories.  But if there are more than 5 posts in a category, only the 5 newest are shown.

How can I show all, or at least set a number like 9 posts etc.?

My code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'child_of' => 1
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach  ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<li><a>'.$category->name.'</a>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use the `posts_per_page` argument in your `get_posts` query:

```
$args = array( 'child_of' => 1 );
$categories = get_categories( $args ); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<li><a>'.$category->name.'</a>';
    echo '<ul>';

    $posts_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'category' => $category->term_id
    );
    foreach (get_posts($posts_args) as $post) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';         
    }  
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The number of posts is set to 5 by default, so you have to set it to your liking. If you want to show all posts, then it's `-1`, and the number you want otherwise.

You should also put functions out of loops (as in your second `foreach`), so here is your code, optimized:

```
<?php  
$args = array(
    'child_of' => 1,
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
if (count($categories)) {
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        ?>
        <li><a><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
        <ul>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // query ALL posts
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'cat' => $category->term_id,
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
        </ul></li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks good, and ready made is far easier to understand & implement! But I think there are some issues with the code?  No close of the if or while?  The 2nd last ?> was not opened?

Comment: You're right, I forgot one `<?php` tag. The rest, however, is fine. What do you mean by _No close of the if or while_? For each there is a code block built by `{ ... }`. And BTW, you should use `wp_reset_postdata` no matter with which solution you end up.

Comment: I got it working thanks, and I prefer this code than to echo the whole html method.  But I had to remove the if function as it did not work with it.  And you had added a <ul> which I had outside the code.  I had been using endif & endwhile but I guess it is not needed here.

Answer (score 2):

You've to make use of the `post_per_page` or `numberposts` parameter of [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts). The parameter defaults to `5`, see [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1678), just chose the value you actually want it to have in your `get_posts()` call and the default value will be overridden.

Comment: I really should learn to be brief. ;) +1

Comment: Haha, thanks your answer on the other hand is ready-made. @tf